# ng-hide is not getting updated dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have below div element with nghide

```html
 <div ng-hide="showdiv" class="btnshowall"> 
    <a class="button button-block round outline"
       style="background: transparent !important;" >
      Show All
    </a>
 </div>
```

and controller as below

```
.controller('mapCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','User','$cordovaGeolocation','geoFireFac','GoogleMapFac','ConnectivityMonitor','PhysioFac','User',
function ($scope, $stateParams,User,$cordovaGeolocation,geoFireFac,GoogleMapFac,ConnectivityMonitor,PhysioFac,User) {

    console.log('called mapctrl');  
    GoogleMapFac.setUserLoc($scope.map);
    $scope.showdiv = User.getShowDiv();


}])
```

and User service as

```
.service('User', ['ToastFac',function(ToastFac){
    return {
         showDiv : false,
        changeShowDiv : function(){
            console.log('in changeShowDiv before change '+this.showDiv);
            this.showDiv = !this.showDiv;
            console.log('in changeShowDiv after change '+this.showDiv);

        },

        getShowDiv : function(){
            return this.showDiv;
        }
```

I am invoking User.changeShowDiv() from google map's marker click event like below

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      alert('store id '+marker.get('store_id'));
      if(User.showDiv){
          console.log('in if');
          User.changeShowDiv();
          console.log('User.showDiv '+User.showDiv);
      }
      else{
          console.log('in else');
          User.changeShowDiv();
          console.log('User.showDiv '+User.showDiv);
      }

});
```

logs are coming as expected

```
in else
services.js:123 in changeShowDiv before change false
services.js:125 in changeShowDiv after change true
services.js:218 User.showDiv true
services.js:211 in if
services.js:123 in changeShowDiv before change true
services.js:125 in changeShowDiv after change false
services.js:213 User.showDiv false
services.js:216 in else
services.js:123 in changeShowDiv before change false
services.js:125 in changeShowDiv after change true
services.js:218 User.showDiv true
```

By default, as User.showDiv variable is false, showAll button is visible. But button is not hiding & coming by marker click events.

Could someone guide me what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're retrieving value from `User.getShowDiv` method once only. But when it gets change your are not updating `showdiv` scope variable. To update value each time you can directly bind the reference of `User.getShowDiv` method to `showdiv` scope variable like below

```
$scope.showdiv = User.getShowDiv;
```

There after call `showdiv` method on HTML, which will eventually evaluate value on each digest cycle unlike other `bindings`.

```
ng-hide="showdiv()"
```

---

Even above would not solve your problem. Basically you're updating some variable from outside context Angular which is `click` event. So you have to run digest cycle manually right after updating value from `click` event listener ran. Just do use `$timeout(angular.noop)` to fire digest cycle safely.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      alert('store id '+marker.get('store_id'));
      if(User.showDiv){
          //Code here
      }
      else{
          //Code here
      }
      //manually triggering digest loop to make binding in sync
      $timeout(angular.noop); //It will run new digest cycle.
});
```

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately, I lost the default behaviour. I am missing something .  Can you correct me in this fiddle.     https://jsfiddle.net/25kkvfdt/3/

Comment: @kpvsrkp give me second, updating mine answer :) I realize one key point that I missed to add

Comment: @kpvsrkp check updated answer.. Even you can refer georgeawg answer. we both has same thing.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Events that come from outside the AngularJS framework need to be brought into the AngularJS framework with [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      alert('store id '+marker.get('store_id'));
      if(User.showDiv){
          console.log('in if');
          User.changeShowDiv();
          console.log('User.showDiv '+User.showDiv);
      }
      else{
          console.log('in else');
          User.changeShowDiv();
          console.log('User.showDiv '+User.showDiv);
      }
      //IMPORTANT
      $scope.$apply();    
});
```

> AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc... You can also use `$apply()` to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript. Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or **when working with third-party library callbacks.**
>
> [image: ff]
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

---

## ALSO

Be sure to fix the `ng-hide` and the controller:

```
<div ng-hide="showdiv()" class="btnshowall">
```

```
$scope.showdiv = function() {
    return User.getShowDiv();
};
```

In the above code, the `ng-hide` directive will execute the `showdiv()` function on each digest cycle and update the visibility of the element accordingly.

Comment: Great +1. silly me :(, I missed this point, I realized this thing just now when I see your edit on post :) You're awesome as always :)

Comment: @georgeawg Is not better use `$evalAsync`?

Comment: It is clear that the event comes from outside the AngularJS framework. `$evalAsync` is more for scheduling async operations from inside the AngularJS execution context.

Comment: @Hadi `$evalAsync`/`$apply`/`$timeout` would have same meaning here as we're running event manually from AngularJS outer world. But yes, for safe side we should either be using  `$evalAsync` or `$timeout`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. @PankajParkar and georgeawg

Comment: Be aware `$timeout` will cause an additional browser render cycle and an additional $digest cycle. Not necessary in this case but some programmers  do it to "be safe".